# WPF style : BasedOn properties not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to keep the style of a DataGrid using BasedOn property but this is what happens :

Before any changes, my DataGrid looks like :

[image]

Then I add the XAML above :

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

And it becomes this :

[image]

You can see that the padding is messed up, the background color, the font...

What is missing? How can I simply keep the style applied THEN add my own few changes on top of the existing one?

Comment: I tried doing this and it works fine for me. Are your sure the style on which you want to BasedOn does not have a key?

Comment: the code is correct. obviously the problem is with other parts of your code

Comment: Thank you for your consideration, I wanted to be sure the code was correct. I can close this subject though